# 200AH lead acid battery

Tags: batteries, power-electronics, battery-operated, electricity, battery-chemistry

I have a 12V 200AH lead acid battery and I want my load be  a power resistor and a bulb. Does the batter draw current based on the load resistance? so meaning the current that will be drawn in this case is 12/(load resistance) ? does a typical bulb require a specific voltage and current?

Comment: Which bulb did you have in mind?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75, hi Sunnysky, welcome again :).  I am trying an idea of testing some relays with this load. I am wondering if there is a bulb that can operate from 6-12V and still be operating properly.  I will also add a power resistor to limit the current going to the blub.

Comment: you can dim LEDstrips from 14.2V down to 8V using a PWM module which you can buy for/with 5m reels

Answer (score 0):

The battery (or any constant voltage power supply) will deliver a current that depends on the supply voltage and load resistance, as determined by Ohm's Law.

Incandescent light bulbs are designed to operate on a specific voltage, depending on their intended operation.  A bulb intended for 12 volt operation (for use in a car) will be instantly destroyed if you try to operate it from 120 volts.  a bulb designed for 120 volts (for use at home) will not produce any useful light when operated from 12 volts (it might get slightly warm).